# How does chrome.devtools.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged event work?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm making extension for Google Chrome DevTools and experiencing a problem with `chrome.devtools.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged` event, which is just never called. Here's a sample from my `devtools_page` code:

```
chrome.devtools.panels.sources.createSidebarPane(pluginTitle, function(sidebar) {
  sidebar.setPage("pane.html");

  var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: 'devtools'});

  port.postMessage({log: 'devtools init'});

  chrome.devtools.panels.sources.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function() {
      port.postMessage({
        log: 'Selection changed'
      });
  });

  port.postMessage({log: 'devtools inited'});
});
```

I get both of "devtools init" and "devtools inited" messages (just to make sure it doesn't fall somewhere), but I never get a "Selection changed" message.

Am I missing something? What exactly `sources.onSelectionChanged` should react to? Do I have enough permissions? My current permissions are:

```
[
  "tabs",
  "nativeMessaging",
  "webNavigation",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "webRequest",
  "*://*/*"
]
```

Comment: Does anything change if you make `port` a global variable there? You could also check for `onDisconnected` event on the port in `pane.html`.

Comment: @Xan yes, I tried that - no difference. I also use `onDisconnect`, it's not called until I close devtools, so the port must be alive (double-checked it with `setInterval`).

Comment: And what are you doing to try and trigger that event precisely?

Comment: @Xan I tried to open files from "Sources" or "Content scripts" files, select some text, clicking here and there, pretty much anything. Docs says it "Fired when an object is selected in the panel" and it looks just like copypaste from ElementsPanel description. I don't understand what does "an object" means in this context.

Comment: Maybe it only works on a custom panel which you add yourself?

Comment: As a reference I created an issue for this. Still unclearified in 2016 :(
https://github.com/google/WebFundamentals/issues/3100